# pygame spritecollide not working with groups

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm making a game that involves the player colliding with hitboxes, and a function that should return True if the player has collided with any of the hitboxes in the group. This works with one hitbox, but if I put the group in the spritecollide function it returns the error "Hitbox object not iterable". I've put the function belowif anyone could help.(Targets is the hitbox group)

```
def CheckCollision(Targets,Player):
for x in Targets:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Player,x,0) == True:
        return(True)
return(False)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) for `spritecollide`.

The first argument should be a `Sprite`; the second argument should be a `Group`.

The error message tells you what's wrong: `x` is not iterable, since it's a `Hitbox`. So stop calling `spritecollide` with `Hitbox` objects and call it with the `Targets` (it should a `Group`)instead:

```
def CheckCollision(Targets, Player):
    return pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Player, Targets,0)
```

But if you only want to know if the `Player` (which should be a `Sprite`) collides with anything in `Targets` (it should a `Group`), then you can simply use [`spritecollideany`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany).

```
def CheckCollision(Targets, Player):
    return pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(Player, Targets)
```

You should use `spritecollide` only if you want to remove Sprites or need a list of all Sprites that intersect with another `Sprite`.